# Excel: Text String to Date Conversion

Tags: excel, date

I have a working formula for the following text to date conversion. However, I don't understand why the trailing 0 has to be added in order to show the year in YYYY format.

21.04.2016  converts to 4/21/2016

```
=(MID(A2,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2,2))+0
```

It's very simple and straight-forward. However if you remove the 0 at the end of the formula, it will only show 16 instead of 2016. But I could do Right(A2,4) instead of Right(A2,2). But I still like to know why? Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Wondering how were you able to find it out that adding the zero would work !! ;)

Comment: Truth is, this code is not from me. I saw it somewhere online. I just don't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Adding a zero makes Excel convert a string into a number, proper formatting makes Excel display the number as a Date.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent  You are too fast!  Go reward yourself with a trip to the local coffee/donut shop!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if we add a 0 to a formula, it automatically converts a string into a number no matter what?

Comment: @lulumink  only in some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trailing zero turns the whole thing into a math operation which causes the string (everything to the left of the +0) to be treated as a number.

you could also use *1 instead of +0

```
=(MID(A2,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2,2))*1
```

or you could drop the +0 and at the front add -- before the ( and it should all do the same.

```
=--(MID(A2,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2,2))
```

Comment: Now, it becomes clear! Thanks alot! If we add a math operator to the formula, Excel treats it like a number instead of anything else. Makes sense!

Answer (score 6):

As Ed has correctly answered, this is because it is treating your date string as a number.

However, Excel has to interpret the string to get what number it really is, and to do this it relies on regional settings.
Under US regional settings, your formula works great, but when I plug it into excel with UK regional settings I get #Value because "04/21/16" isn't a valid date or number in the UK.

In order to avoid this problem, you should convert it to a date using the DATE() function, which will work irrespective of your regional settings.

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))
```

Comment: Thanks Phil for the alternative solution! Works like a charm too!.

Comment: This is the better answer, avoiding relying on local settings to dis-ambiguate the date

Comment: Agreed that this is the better way to convert the date and totally support this as the answer (read upvote) to get the date from a string into an excel date value...but technically the question was essentially "what the heck is the +0 doing?"  But that might be splitting hairs.

Comment: Another advantage of using the `DATE()`function is that the cell will automatically a reasonable format

Comment: @ForwardEd I completely agree that this wasn't really the question, but the title of the question was screaming out for this clarification and I didn't have comment priviledges

Comment: Its actually a very common problem that pops up on here and it also prevents the datevalue () function from working right.

Comment: @Phil I really appreciate your answer and I also agree that yours is best solution. However, Forward Ed answered first and also answered the question of my thread. I was just curious about that trailing zero. I think it would be fair to give him the vote this time. Hope you'll understand. Thanks.